# What is the efficient way to perform 2D matrix filtering in python?

Tags: python, numpy, filtering

I am trying to implement a matrix filtering in Python, and so far the implementation appears to be very slow and inefficient. I wonder if there is an efficient way of performing such filtering.

Provided a large matrix A and a filtering matrix M, the function should return a "remixed" matrix R which is obtained by multiplying each element (i,j) of A by M, then the result is superposed/inserted into R at position (i,j). Please find below the code that is expected to do this.

The example below takes about 68 sec (!) at my computer, which seems very inefficient.

I would be very grateful if you could recommend the way to speed-up this function. Many thanks in advance!

```py
import numpy as np
import time

nx = ny = 1500
n_mix = 50

# matrix to be filtered
A = np.random.random_sample( (nx, ny) )

# filter to be applied to each point:
M = np.random.random_sample( (2*n_mix+1, 2*n_mix+1) )

# the result is stored in "remix":
remix = np.zeros_like(A)

start = time.time()

for i in range(n_mix, nx-n_mix):
    for j in range(n_mix, ny-n_mix):
        remix[i - n_mix:i + n_mix + 1, j - n_mix:j + n_mix + 1 ] += M * A[i,j]

print remix

duration = time.time() - start
print(round(duration))
```

**UPDATE**

In fact the ndimage package in scipy has the general convolution function that does the job. I post below the 3 variants of doing the filtering, with respected times. The fastest is with ndimage.convolution (24 seconds vs. 56 and 68 by other methods). However, it still seems rather slow...

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import time
import sys


def remix_function(A, M):
    n = (np.shape(M)[0]-1)/2
    R = np.zeros_like(A)

    for k in range(-n, n+1):
        for l in range(-n, n+1):
            # Ak  = np.roll(A, -k, axis = 0)
            # Akl = np.roll(Ak, -l, axis = 1)
            R += np.roll(A, (-k,-l), axis = (0,1) ) * M[n-k, n-l]
    return R

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

    nx = ny = 1500
    n_mix = 50
    nb = 2*n_mix+1

    # matrix to be filtered
    A = np.random.random_sample( (nx, ny) )
    # filter to be applied to each point:
    M = np.random.random_sample( (nb, nb) )


    # the result is stored in "remix":
    remix1 = np.zeros_like(A)
    remix2 = np.zeros_like(A)
    remix3 = np.zeros_like(A)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# var 1
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    start = time.time()

    remix1 = remix_function(A, M)

    duration = time.time() - start
    print('time for var1 =', round(duration))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# var 2
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    start = time.time()

    for i in range(n_mix, nx-n_mix):
        for j in range(n_mix, ny-n_mix):
            remix2[i - n_mix:i + n_mix + 1, j - n_mix:j + n_mix + 1 ] += M * A[i,j]


    duration = time.time() - start
    print('time for var2  =', round(duration))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# var 3
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    start = time.time()

    remix3 = ndimage.convolve(A, M)

    duration = time.time() - start
    print('time for var3 (convolution) =', round(duration))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on posts yet, but your double for loop is the problem. Have you tried defining a function and then using np.vectorize?